# Protractor/Jasmine : match with <quantity to be determined>

Tags: jasmine, integration-testing, protractor

I'm writing a protractor test for angular code that adds an item to a list displayed with ng-repeat.
I want to check that when the user clicks a button, another item is added to the list within a few hundred milliseconds.
The initial count of items is unknown.

The test pseudocode is like this :

```
var e = element.all(by.repeater(...))
getButtonPromise().click() // -> XHR to server, which adds item to list
expect(e.count()).toBe(XXX)
```

Constraints :

1) the initial number of items must be measured BEFORE the click is executed

2) the expected value is (the initial value + 1)

3) expect(...) must be run periodically until timeout or list count has reached the expected value

4) the control flow for the rest of the test must be stopped until expect(...) resolves to success or timeout

I have tried various approaches but nothing works.
Your help in solving this common testing pattern is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = element.all(by.repeater(...))

e.count().then(function(oldCount) {
  getButtonPromise().click();
  browser.wait(function() {
    return e.count().then(function(newCount) {
      return newCount === oldCount + 1;
    })
  }, YOUR_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);

  expect(e.count()).toEqual(oldCount + 1); // this is optional because if this isn't true, it would have timed out already.

})
```